# How to get select item data from QComboBox populated with QSqlTableModel

Tags: python, pyqt, qcombobox, qsqltablemodel

I have a basic combo box populated with data from an sqlite3 database table:

```
self.langModel = QSqlTableModel(self)
self.langModel.setTable("languages")
self.langModel.setSort(self.langModel.fieldIndex("label"), Qt.AscendingOrder)
self.langModel.select()

...

self.comboLangs = QComboBox()
self.comboLangs.setModel(self.langModel)
self.comboLangs.setModelColumn(self.langModel.fieldIndex("label"))
self.layout.addRow("Language", self.comboLangs)

...

self.btnAdd = QPushButton("Add")
self.btnAdd.clicked.connect(self.addLoc)
self.btnLayout.addWidget(self.btnAdd)

...

def addLoc(self):
    pprint(vars(self.langModel.data(self.langModel.index(self.comboLangs.currentIndex(), self.langModel.fieldIndex("iso")))))
```

Here is the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE languages ( 
    id    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    iso   TEXT    NOT NULL,
    label TEXT    NOT NULL 
);
```

This just produces an empty dict `{}`. How do I get the selected/current item's data object from the QSqlTableModel?

Answer (score 4):

Okay figured it out (I wish the PyQt reference documentation was a little bit more specific on how to do this). Anyhow, to get the model data I needed to convert the QVariant object to either a Python object (toPyObject()) or to a tring (toString()).

```
print self.langModel.data(self.langModel.index(self.comboLangs.currentIndex(), self.langModel.fieldIndex("iso"))).toString()
```

This got me the data I needed.